# How to avoid segmentation fault for the below program?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fcount(char ch, char *a){
    if(*a == '\n'){
        printf("d");
        return 0;
    }
    else
        if(*a == ch){
            printf("b");
            return 1 + fcount(ch, a++);
        }
        else
           if(*a!=ch){
                return fcount(ch, a++);
        }
}

int main(){
    char *s;
    int c = 0, i;
    printf("Enter anything you wish\n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",s);
    for(i = 97; i <= 122; i++){
        c = fcount(i, s);
        if(c != 0)
            printf("[%c] %d\n", i, c);
    }
}
```

This is my logic to count the frequency of each character in a given line of text
But the program doesnt seem to display the expected output

what I get is this: Segmentation fault(Core dumped)
Please offer me some advice!

Comment: `char *s;` has no memory allocation: it is an uninitialised pointer. Suggest `char s[1024];` for example and limit the input length in `scanf`.

Comment: `char s[100];` and `scanf("%99[^\n]", s);`, note that you don't need the `s` in the format specifier.

Comment: Aside: avoid hard coded number magic: `for(i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)` (assumes consecutive encoding, but that is *usually* the case).

Comment: You **mustn't** have the `s` after the `%[^\n]` in your format.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer value that you passed in `scanf` is uninitialized. Accessing that garbage value invokes Undefined behavior.

Allocate some memory and then pass it to `scanf`.

You can simply use `char s[10]`. Or you can allocate it dynamically.

```
s = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
if( s == NULL){
   fprintf(stderr,"%s"<"Error in malloc");
   exit(1);
}

..

free(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

's' is character pointer and its not pointing to any valid memory. Either take static array like s[100] or allocate memory dynamically.

```
char *s;
```

replace above statement with

```
char *s =  malloc(n*sizeof(char)); // scan 'n' value from user.
```

and once work is done, free the dynamically allocated memory using free() function.

```
free(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated memory to `s`. Use malloc for that.

```
char *s;
s=(char*)malloc(21*sizeof *s); // Suppose you want at the most 20 chars in s
if(NULL == s){
    printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
    exit(1); // Exiting with a non-zero exit status
}

//Also, instead of scanf use fgets
fgets(s,21,stdin); // Does some bounds checking.
s[strlen(s)-1]='\0';  //  Getting rid of newline character at the end, so mallocing 21 makes sense
```